# How to change Skype's port

Tags: networking, configuration, skype

I have got some problems with Skype, and I was wondering if there was any way to change which port Skype listens on? Like in the settings or anywhere that wouldn't cause any problems? If this is even possible that is...

Comment: Just change it in settings. But that won't change anything.

Comment: I'm confused, what do you want to change the listening port for?

Comment: @ThomasW.: I just need to check something out for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open skype's *Options* window, select the *Advanced* tab and enter your desired port number into the number field on the right. You should just take care that the new port is not already used by any other application and that you chose a number greater than 1023, as those are reserved.

[image]