# Pidgin "Failed getting magic T value"

Tags: email, pidgin

I installed pidgin because I wanted to sync my MS account through Skype (as it is one with Microsoft).

After installing Skype in Pidgin I add an account. In the **modify** window there's a **Basic** tab, **Advanced** tab and a **Proxy** tab. I didn't touch **Advanced** or **Proxy** just the **Basic** tab. I choose Skype (HTTP) on the Protocol, type my username & password & check the box. After that, it says that it had an error.

[image: Screenshot Link]

Now, I don't know what to do to enable my account through pidgin. I log in my Skype through web browser and still can't connect. What should I do?

Comment: I installed pidgin. I wanted to sync my MS acct with it since Skype is connected with Microsoft. Now I'm getting this error message: "Failed to getting magic T value."

Comment: There's a nice [flowchart](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb#issues) for `skypeweb` that you can check. It covers questions like, are you using the latest version, are you using two-factor authentication, is there maybe something Skype needs to you to do (accept a new version of the TOS), etc.

Comment: @MelloHat: Unfortunately that is too vague. Please [edit] your question to describe *every step in detail* that you took to set up Skype for Pidgin and to connect to it.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I followed the flowchart but still no progress. All I did is to **delete** and **add** account, just configure the my pidgin and didn't touch the other _tabs_.

Comment: @Zanna Thank you for editing my question...Still got stuck on my pidgin. I still can't configure it out.

Comment: You may find [this useful](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/issues/507) as well as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/638133/how-to-change-skypes-port)

Answer (score 4):

Logging into web.skype.com fixed this issue for me and others. After you should be able to login via pidgin. I believe this resets the token and or once the security check has been completed on web.skype.com it no longer blocks pidgin.

Answer (score 1):

If your password contains certain special characters (`\`, `'`, `"`, and possibly others), you will get this error message. Removing these problematic characters from your password (or escaping them with `\` when you enter your password in pidgin or bitlbee) will solve the problem.

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/issues/601). This thread might also cover your problem if it is a different one.

Also, as pointed out by @Henning Kockerbeck, there is a helpful flowchart [here](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb#issues).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by @prosoitos. [This](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb#issues) is a useful flowchart. From that I solved my issue which threw the same error message.

In my case I was using two-factor-authentication (recommended for security). So as per the flow-chart I simply needed to:

1. Create a new app password at the [MS security settings page](https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage?mkt=en-us) and copy it.
2. In Pidgin open the <kbd>Modify Account</kbd> for my Skype account.
3. Paste the new app password into the <kbd>password</kbd> field.
4. In the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> tab tick the <kbd>Use alternative login method</kbd> checkbox.

#### Mirror of the flowchart for redundancy:

[image: A flowchart detailing the process of troubleshooting]